# Ruby on Rails convert javascript to coffee

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, fullcalendar

What's a good way to learn how to convert javascript to coffeescript?

I'm adding Fullcalendar to my RoR app.  The following code is from one of the Fullcalendar demos.

```
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
```

I need to learn how to turn that code into coffeescript.

Thanks!

Comment: "convert javascript to coffee" - well, usually programmers do it the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) page has a good comparison.

In rails you can append .coffee to your javascript filename and sprockets will then compile the CoffeeScript into javascript.

It should look something like this:

```
        select: (start, end, allDay) ->
        title = prompt 'Event Title:'
        if title
            calendar.fullCalendar 'renderEvent',
              title: title,
              start: start,
              end: end,
              allDay: allDay,
            true
        calendar.fullCalendar 'unselect'
```

Answer (score 2):

- Go to http://js2coffee.org
- Or you can download js2coffee and do it from the command line
- Or you can do it the hard way by typing it yourself
  http://coffeescript.org (try coffescript tab)